# Object movement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

Suppose we have two objects a car and an orange. The car is moving at 100MPH in a straight line. I throw the orange in the air when the car is still moving. Will the orange move with the car or essential hit the back window?

Comment: Why should it move with the car? Are you sitting in the car while throwing? Some details are missing here...

Comment: Steeven yes that’s correct. Sorry I’m completely new to this sort of stuff

Comment: There are lots of duplicates of your question on this site, but when you get someone else to drive, and then  toss a coin upwards, you can test this yourself......hint.  can people walk-up the aisles of aircraft moving at 500 mph....the constant velocity makes no difference

Comment: Countto10 Is there a explanation / theory that I can read up on this?

Comment: The orange has the velocity of the car as well. Everything inside the car has the velocity of the car.

Comment: Sure, this site http://zonalandeducation.com/mstm/physics/mechanics/forces/newton/newtonLaw1.html. is very good and if you use the search box on the upper right hand of this page  you will see duplicate of your question. Or just google, why does an orange (or a balloon or anything) not move backwards when I let it go in a moving car

Comment: PLEASE, be more specific.  Are you a passenger in the car when you throw the orange?  Are you throwing the orange horizontally, vertically, or at an angle?  How fast are you throwing the orange?

Comment: David White Passanger, vertically, 5MPH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principles of Newton state that, in an inertial frame, if there is no force applied to an object it will not accelerate. The fact is that this law is valid in $\textit{all}$ inertial frames.

Let me illustrate another similar example first. Suppose that you are in the car, speeding at some velocity $v$ in some direction. The motion of the car is uniform: it does not change velocity (module or direction). Take a very long straight road for this example. The frame in which the car is still at the origin of the axes (that is commonly called the frame of the car) is still an inertial frame, due to the fact that the car is moving with constant velocity, so the principles of Newton are still valid.

Now you take your orange and you start juggling with it (possibly, don't be the driver in this case). You launch it upward, let it arrive to a maximum heigth and then catch it as it falls into your hands. Now, as there is no net force on the orange on the horizontal axis (there is gravity on the vertical, making the orange fall), you expect it to travel straight upwards, and it does.

Suppose that the driver sees a Schrodinger's cat crossing the road and actionates the brakes not to have him collapse in the "dead cat" autostate. You're still juggling your orange, but now the car's frame is no more inertial: you observe the orange speeding towards your shoulders and it splashes on the front window. You conclude that a force on the horizontal axis has caused the splashing. That's an apparent force, because it is caused by your being in a non inertial frame.

Let us observe your juggling from outside the car, standing still. You see the car speeding at speed $v$, and the passenger is juggling his orange in the same way as before. The difference is that now the orange has an horizontal speed $v$. This is correct: the orange moves with the car and the passenger, so it falls right into the passeger's hands. When you see the cat crossing and the car braking, you see that the airborne orange still has its $v$ component on the horizontal axis, but the front window is rapidly decreasing its velocity: eventually the orange (that will continue traveling at $v$ on the horizzontal axis, as there is no horizontal force on it) will reach the front window and splash against it. You conclude that no force acted on the ball.

This long preamble is to illustrate you that there is no absolute speed, and no absolute description in terms of frames (if you take into account fictious forces for noninertial frames). Let us go to your case: you are an uncivilized passenger and drop the orange from the window. Now, the term "dropping" may be interpreted as "releasing an object to fall with no initial velocity, in the frame of the person dropping the object". The specification of the frame is fundamental: when you give a speed you must give a frame in which the speed is measured. So, you drop the orange and see it splashing exactly below you. An outside observer would observe both you and the orange traveling at $v$ horizontally.

If you "throw" the orange at a certain velocity $w$, it is usually meant with respect to your frame. So, in this example, the outside observer would see the orange thrown at velocity $v+w$.

Hope this helps, in any case feel free to comment.